# Preselect first option on knockout.js generated radio list

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I am new to knockout.js and managed to generate a radio button list. But I don't know how to preselect the first radio button on the list. Here is (I think) a excerpt of the important part of the code:

knockout.js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/external/rest/api/' + zipCode,
    type: 'GET',
    context: document.body
}).done(
    function (response) {
        $.each(response, function(key, droppoint) {
            self.droppoints.push(droppoint);
        });
    }
).fail(

);
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $parents[1].droppoints" >
  <label>
    <input class="droppoint_radio" type="radio"
           name="droppoint_location" 
           data-bind="attr: {value: number}" />
    <div class="droppoint_address">
      <div data-bind="text: company_name"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited the question to remove/change references to "radio button" since this isn't about radio buttons.

Comment: Actually, I included the wrong code, that has been corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control a radio button in knockout with the `checked` binding. You can add an observable `selectedPoint` that represents the selected radio button and assign this observable the value of the first radio button.

Depending on your javascript, this might look like this:

```
viewModel.selectedPoint = ko.observable();
```

Adding the `checked` binding to the HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $parents[1].droppoints" >
    <label>
        <input class="droppoint_radio" type="radio"
            name="droppoint_location" 
            data-bind="attr: {value: number},
            checked: $parents[2].selectedPoint" />
        <div class="droppoint_address">
            <div data-bind="text: company_name"></div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

Finally, set the number of the first droppoint as default value in the AJAX callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/external/rest/api/' + zipCode,
    type: 'GET',
    context: document.body
}).done(
    function (response) {
        $.each(response, function(key, droppoint) {
            self.droppoints.push(droppoint);
        });
        self.selectedPoint(response[0].number);
    }
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong code previously. I have corrected it.